# Screens fade to blurry

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen

This is a awkard behaviour the one I suffer. When I have more than one application open, the ones without focus start fading or flicking to a blurry state, to the point that you can't almost read the text on it.
As I can't attach images, here's the link: [this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lNod.jpg).
The monitor resolutions are right, and changing them doesn't fix anything.
I'm using privative drivers. I don't know what any other information could be useful so feel free to ask.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the source for this problem; a random crash of "TVGuiSlave" proccess and the monitor came back to normal.
This is then related to Teamviewer, which I have removed from the startup applications list to avoid this.